# For loop inside <<-eos Ruby

Tags: ruby, string, loops, for-loop

I'm a rookie in Ruby language. I'm trying to write a json file with ruby to import it after to a Mongodb collection. I need the document maintain proper indentation to then fill it comfortably

At this moment, I'm doing it in this way, but I'm sure that isn't the recommened way

```
    out_file = File.new('file.json', "w+")
    str = <<-eos
    {
        "key1": #{@value1},
        "key2" :  #{@value2},
        "key3" : {
            "subkey_3_1" : {
                "key" : #{@value},
                "questions" : #{@invalid_questions}
            },
            "subkey_3_2" : {
                "key" : #{value},
                "array_key" : [
                   for i in 1..50
                     # Here, must be create 50 hash pair-value like this. 
                    {},
                    {},
                    {},
                    ...
                    end
                ] 
            }
        }
    }
    eos

    out_file.puts(str)
    out_file.close
```

This is the final structure that I want.Thanks, and sorry for not explaining right from the start

How can I define it in ruby?

Comment: But you can first create a Hash and then use `out_file.puts(hash.to_json)`.. Very easy. Look this [example](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.0.0/libdoc/json/rdoc/JSON.html#module-JSON-label-Generating+JSON)

Comment: Thanks! to_json function works!

Answer (score 0):

```
str = <<-eos    
"key" : [
    #{for i in 1..50 {
          ...something content...
         }.join("\n") }              
] 
eos
```

However - why do you want a string here - I don't know what you are trying to do, but there must be a better way of doing it.

UPDATE:

Yep, as mentioned by @ArupRakshit you need to create the hash first and call `to_json` on it. If you don't have this method, you need to install gem called `active_support` and require 'active_support/core_ext' (no need to do this for rails app). Do not build json response manually.

Comment: Sorry, just updated the question for you can understand it better